# Allvideodownloader replacement

Tags: linux, video, download-manager, media-converter, ipod

I downloaded [Allvideodownloader](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/allvideodownloader/) for Ubuntu 13.10, and it was the perfect YouTube downloader. It converted the videos for me so I could play them on my iPod classic, and even did MP3, all in one place.

I upgraded to Linux Mint 16, but I can't get Allvideodownloader to work on it. I'm looking for a replacement for it, but I'm not sure what to get. I want something just like it, that **downloads videos from YouTube and other sites**, will convert them to **MP3, MP4 for iPod classic**.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations Stack Exchange! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/50) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.

Comment: Why don't you use a webapp to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to use two seperate programs here.

### Downloading Videos

First I would recommend [JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/) to download the actual videos

JDownloader is a free, open source, download management tool that supports downloading videos from Youtube, as well as from many other sites. JDownloader is licensed under GPL and is available on Linux, Windows, and OS X.

Some features of JDownloader include

- Download multiple files at once
- Pause and resume downloads
- Download playlists
- Broad website support

[image: JDownloader]

### Transcoding

Next I would recommend [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) for the actual file conversion (transcoding). Handbrake is a free, open source, all-in-one transcode tool available on Linux, Windows, and OS X.

[image: Handbrake]

Handbrake's most notable features include

- Built-in device presets
- Broad codec support
- Batch conversions and conversion queue
- Subtitle and chapter support

The main reason I'd recommend Handbrake is for its built-in presets. Among the ones selectable, there are transcode presets for

- iPod
- iPhone & iPod touch
- iPad
- AppleTV
- AppleTV 2
- AppleTV 3
- Android
- Android Tablet

After downloading a Youtube video with JDownloader, you would simply select the iPod preset in Handbrake, start the transcode, and then be finished with it once the conversion is complete.

---

<sup>Source on the first half of my post: [YouTube downloader for Ubuntu](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2139/youtube-downloader-for-ubuntu)</sup>