# Download Manager for URLs in Windows

Tags: windows, download-manager

I have searched 'everywhere' for this...

When I start a Google Chrome download, and if I want to pause the download and turn off my computer, the download fails. I need a software that would let me continue my download from where I left off.

Is there a Windows (7 or 8) program which downloads Chrome downloads (URLs) a bit like μTorrent®?

Comment: This is really too broad - like on [download.com there are at least 400](http://download.cnet.com/windows/download-managers/?tag=bc) that match what you have specified. ***(if you do get something off of download.com be very careful of adware and the like in their installers)*** Basically any download manager that is not only a video (ie YouTube) downloader will do exactly that - on most servers some servers are not configured to allow download pausing/resuming and nothing you do on your end will change that.

Comment: If you are really looking for a good download manager rather than Chrome extensions, try 'IDM'(Internet Download Manager). Its awesome. I think its the fastest one and I personally use it. But the only problem is that it is not free. You will be able to use it for 30 days. After that, I think you know what to do. If you are looking for a free download manager, try the 'Free Download Manager'. I had used it too. Its good.

Comment: Check my answer here, I wrote it for videos, but the second program will also work for any type of links and files (file download manager & download accelerator). **It's exactly like Internet Download Manager but it's free**  -> (http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/817/software-to-download-youtube-videos-to-hard-drive/912#912)

Comment: @TomJ Yes, IDM is really good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [DownloadAll](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/downloadall/ajffocjdcmpgjmdfdfkdfdbkjafbkcke?hl=en) Chrome extension. It allows you to pause downloads & resume them later. Typically I have found the download rates to be higher via this extension rather than when downloading through Chrome (although I dont know why).

Provides all the standard features of a downloader, such as load balancing i.e., you can set speed limits for individual downloads, view the download in the folder or open it directly etc.