# Freeware software to download YouTube videos from web proxy services

Tags: gratis, windows-7, video, download-manager, youtube

I use web sites like [video-proxy.com](http://video-proxy.com) to view YouTube videos, as YouTube is blocked in my university. Can someone recommend softwares to download videos from YouTube? Something like [IDM](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/).

Requirements:

- Channel and video download (format doesn’t matter)
- Freeware

I’m using Windows 7. I am connected to university LAN and my system is behind a proxy.

Softwares already tried and not working

- IDM (Trial expired)
- JDownloader (Unalble to parse)
- Freemake Video Downloader (connection error??)
- DAP
- DownloadAll Chrome extension
- EagleGet

Comment: I never used it behind proxy, so not sure how it plays.. but [YouTube-dl](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/index.html) have this option too, & works on unix and windows, Its a command line tool although

Comment: Would a Firefox Addon be an acceptable answer?

Comment: addons are also fine.

Comment: Related: *[Software to download YouTube videos to hard drive](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/817)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't give you a **standalone application**, but the alternative one is **web application**. [ClipConverter CC](http://www.clipconverter.cc/) is allowing you to convert and download your Youtube video in the version what you like.
I hadn't tried it before using proxy services on my school. But, I hope it will work.