# How to download video as mp3 from internet?

Tags: video, audio, media-converter, download-manager, mp3

I can download YouTube video using Chrome extension. Is there any way to download video as mp3?

I tried many sites, but nothing seems to work reliably.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to download youtube video in mp3 format?

Comment: A quick Google Search showed me http://www.video2mp3.net/ & http://www.youtube-mp3.org/? Did you tried them? They are all working perfectly.

Comment: @SriHarshaKappala I tried, and it works fine sometimes. They are really not reliable. I am searching for something like Chrome extension.

Comment: How about [Desktop software to convert YouTube files to MP3](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/750/desktop-software-to-convert-youtube-files-to-mp3)?